# Get selected cell element datatables

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a table with matches from where when i click the odd it displays in a div the clicked odd.
This is my table:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="display1" name="display1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Teams</th>
  <th>1</th>
  <th>X</th>
  <th>2</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>Etoile - Bizertin</td>
  <td><a href="#">1.34</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">0.34</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">0.35</a></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <div id="selectedOption"></div>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
<script>
var table = $('#display1').DataTable();
$('#display1 tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
    $("#selectedOption").html(table.cell(this).data());
});
</script>
```

I want that when i click 1, x or 2 to  display:

Team1-Team2 Odd

Etoile - Bizertin 1.34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Table.cell(this)` is non-sense. Use

I've added a condition using `index()` to prevent inserting team names into `#selectedOption` div.

```
var table = $('#display1').DataTable();
$('#display1 tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
    // prevent click to the first cell with team names
    if ($(this).index() !== 0) {
        $("#selectedOption").html($(this).text());
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to display team names, but i dont know how

Comment: Etoile - Bizertin 1.34

Comment: @Raina21: something like https://jsfiddle.net/obvr604x/? I've commented the datatables, of jsfiddle aren't linked.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is what you were looking for i guess.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var table = $('#display1').DataTable();
table.on('click','td,th', function () {
   $("#selectedOption").html($(this).text());
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="display1" name="display1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Teams</th>
  <th>1</th>
  <th>X</th>
  <th>2</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>Etoile - Bizertin</td>
  <td><a href="#">1.34</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">0.34</a></td>
  <td><a href="#">0.35</a></td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <div id="selectedOption"></div>
```

I hope this helps your problem.